# Oracle JDeveloper studio 12c with JBOSS EAP?

Tags: java, jdeveloper, jboss-eap-6

I have java web application which runs on JBOSS EAP6. I wanted to use Oracle JDeveloper studio for my coding and unit testing of application. Could you please let me know if i am good to use Oracle JDeveloper studio to run my application by configuring JBOSS EAP in the IDE?

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [oracle site](https://www.oracle.com/application-development/technologies/jdeveloper/122-cert.html),you can see that EAP 5 is supported with Oracle JDeveloper studio 12c but not mentioned any information about EAP6,please raise your query on [JDEVELOPER AND ADF community](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/r/apexds/community/questions?domain=dev-community&clear=RP,1&p1_tags=application-development-in-java,jdeveloper-and-adf&p1_category_id=323434627485186785626471144154565580935) so that will get your answer.